# MATLAB: Check if a value in a cell array remains the same

Tags: arrays, matlab, equality, cell-array

My question may be a bit "silly", but I am stucked here, so I would really need your help.

So, we have a cell array Q *5520x1*, like the one below:

[image]

I'm only interested in the first two numbers of each row. To be specifically clear, giving

K>> Q{1}

> ans = 0     1     0   238

I only care about 0 and 1, and so on with the other rows. *Only the first two numbers of each row.* Let's just ignore the rest values in each row of Q, they are more or less irrelevant.

My problem is, how is it possible to check if the first value of each row in the cell array Q, in the example above 0, remains the same? What I would like to achieve, is *while the first value is the same, I want to store in another cell array, all the second values*. In case of number 0, I want to store the values

> [1,3,127,129,216,217,252,253,302,303,342,343]

and so on. How could this be done?

Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Then, when thevalue change to 1, the program stops?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior No, it does not stop, it continues in the same way described, for value 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Do all elements in `Q` have the same size, i.e. are vectors with 4 elements? And as result, you basically want to have one cell for each unique value in the first column?

Comment: @Nemesis Yes, they are vectors with 4 elements, all of them. As a result, i want to have a cell array where all the "second" values of each unique value in the first column will be stored separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% Example Q
Q = {[0 1 135 134];
     [0 3 154 26];
     [0 16 146 234];
     [1 2 324 125];
     [1 7 213 252]};
A = cell2mat(Q(1:2760));
[~,~,ind2] = unique(A(:,1));
C = arrayfun(@(x)A(find(ind2==x),2),1:max(ind2),'UniformOutput',false);

C{1}

ans =

     1
     3
    16

C{2}

ans =

     2
     7
```

Comment: You can use `max(ind2)` instead of `length(ind)` and avoid `ind`

Comment: More accurate answer than Luis' one. But both answers worked for me, but there is a drawback: For some reason, they also store unwanted values. To be specific, value 1 is related to values [2,126,128,216,217,252,253,302,303,342,343]. Trying your way Nemesis, gives: http://gyazo.com/1bad5e92956d9481ea967568bb046e0d for K>> C{2}

ans =

     2
   126
   128
   216
   217
   252
   253
   302
   303
   342
   343
     0

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. However, I need to see the complete `Q` then. Does it happens for @LuisMendo solution also?

Comment: Indeed, it is strange. How could i give you complete Q? Yes @LuisMendo solution was a little more inaccurate. You both guys are really close, you are suggesting similiar things and at first i thought they were just perfect but no eventually until now.

Comment: If possible, save `Q` as `.mat` file and upload it somewhere. Then share the download link. However, only if you are allowed to share to data.

Comment: @Nemesis I did as you told me, here it is the dl link (100% safe): http://www.megafileupload.com/8Xb0/Q.mat

Comment: Check `Q{2761}`. There, the second column is 0, while the first is 1, therefore it goes into `C{2}`. See: `vertcat(Q{2760:2762}); ans =   398   399     0   238;     1     0     0   238;     3     0     1    84`. Please specify how this should be taken into account by the program. Should the 0 go to the other elements with `1` in the first column or should it be in a separate cell?

Comment: @Nemesis This cell Q is a cell that contains constraints between variables. From Q{2761} and later, these constraints are just inverted until the end of the Q. We care only about from the start Q{1} until Q{2760}. The values which are in the second column, are the ones that we want to store for each unique variable in the first column.

Comment: Nice to know. :)  You should specify this in the question. See my edit here and check if this _hard_ limit is sufficient for you. I guess, @LuisMendo solution will be also correct then, when you specify the limits of `Q`.

Comment: All right, that's it! Thank you very much for your time, solution found! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as follows:

```
Q = {[0 1 0 238]
     [0 3 1 84]
     [1 2 1 85]
     [3 4 5 6]}; %// example data. Cell array of equal-size row vectors
Qm = vertcat(Q{:}); %// convert Q into matrix
[vals, ~, id] = unique(Qm(:,1)); %// get unique id for 1st col
result = accumarray(id, Qm(:,2), [], @(x){x.'}); %'// gather 2nd col values according to id
```

This gives:

```
vals =
     0
     1
     3

result{1} =
     1     3
result{2} =
     2
result{3} =
     4
```

Comment: Probably a bit faster then mine.

Comment: @Nemesis Yes, `arrayfun` is essentially a loop, and `accumarray` is probably faster. But that may depend on array size and Matlab version

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the answer, but no it does not return the values i was expecting. It starts really well with accurate values, but later on the results are totally wrong! :-(

Comment: @NickH "Totally wrong"? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @LuisMendo Please,  read the above comments with Nemesis. Your solution was just about the same(even faster in terms of performance).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a for loop :

```
cell_range = max(cellfun(@(x) x(1),Q));
C = cell(cell_range,1)
for i = 1:length(Q)
    M = Q{i};
    disp(M(1));
    C{M(1)} = [C{M(1)}, M(2)];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it returns error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."